# How to create Help view for android application?

Tags: android, android-view

How to create the following help view for android application. This image is from Zapya application and it's appear after first open.

[image]

Comment: In you launcher activity check for a preference like FIRST_LAUNCH. The preference won't be found in first launch. So, when its not found start a activity with theme dialog to start the Help Activity and set the preference a value so that it'll be found next time the application launches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try TourGuide(https://github.com/worker8/TourGuide).

screenshot(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/worker8/all_my_media_files/695d9a2/2015-07-01_screenshot.png)

Or MaterialIntroView(https://github.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView).

screenshot(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iammert/MaterialIntroView/master/art/materialintroviewgif.gif)

Or you can do it simply.

Change layout to :

```
<FrameLayout>
    <your rootView/>
    <your guideView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

When people enter this page,you show your guideView.When people click the next,you hide guideView.The transparent area can be implemented by adding a same view in your rootView or changing the ondraw of your guideView.